# Themeleaf looping using th:each

Tags: java, loops, thymeleaf

I am trying to go through a list from a db and post it on an html form. The only way I got it to work was by using the following code:

```
<tr th:each="customer: ${rxReqBean.iCustomer}">     
        <p type="hidden" th:text="'First Name: ' + ${rxReqBean.iCustomer.get(0).firstName}"/></p>
```

as shown I get the same name over and over. Is there a way to change it to return every first name in the db? the db page is the iCustomer object

Comment: Did you forget to add your code?

Comment: <tr th:each="customer: ${rxReqBean.iCustomer}">     
        <p type="hidden" th:text="'First Name: ' + ${rxReqBean.iCustomer.get(0).firstName}"/></p>

Comment: I didnt forget, it just went blank and when I tried editing to add it, it wouldnt let me

Comment: SO is trying to render your code as an html tag. Add 4 spaces before code to put it inside a codeblock.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are always referencing the first customer of the list by using `get(0)` in  `${rxReqBean.iCustomer.get(0).firstName}`, you have to use your iteration variable instead: `${customer.firstName}`.